# Installing postgresql for Django

Tags: django, postgresql, installation

I installed postgresql and (I think) pyscopg2. I want to run postgresql with django. I tried the command "createdb mydb", and I got the error message shown below. What should I do?

could not connect to database postgres:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am running a mac osx 10.8.2.

When I type in `ps auwwx|grep postg` I get:

```
robbie          27589   0.0  0.0  2443176   1528   ??  Ss    7:25am   0:00.01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process       
robbie          27588   0.0  0.0  2443044    552   ??  Ss    7:25am   0:00.01 postgres: wal writer process       
robbie          27587   0.0  0.0  2443044    592   ??  Ss    7:25am   0:00.16 postgres: writer process       
robbie          27586   0.0  0.0  2443044    612   ??  Ss    7:25am   0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process       
robbie          27584   0.0  0.1  2443044   3524   ??  S     7:25am   0:00.02 /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
robbie          27626   0.0  0.0  2423572     24 s000  S+    7:36am   0:00.00 grep postg
robbie          27590   0.0  0.0  2439324    444   ??  Ss    7:25am   0:00.01 postgres: stats collector process
```

When I type in `psql -V I` get:  `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.4`
When I type in `which psql` I get:`/usr/bin/psql`

Comment: As the error message says..Is your postgresql instance running? Which environment are you on?

Comment: Have you tried connecting via psql? like psql -U user databse_name

Comment: psql -U user databse_name

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the same error.

Comment: how do you start/stop postgres? I am not sure about mac but in ubuntu/gentoo you can use -- sudo service postgresql status or sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-version status -- to check status of the service in case you run it as a service.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect in 2 different ways to PostgreSQL:

1. Unix sockets. They are special files on your filesystem that process can write into and read from.
2. TCP sockets, which main purpose is to allow inter-machine communications on top of the Internet Protocol, but that can very well be used to connect 2 processes on the same machine.

The error message you're getting tells you that Django attempted method one, looking for a special file representing a Unix socket, but didn't succeed. It's very likely that your PostgreSQL instance listens on TCP sockets instead of Unix sockets. To confirm this, try to connect to PostgreSQL using the `psql` command line client like this:

```
psql -h localhost -U user databse_name
```

If you're successful, then you can configure Django to connect to localhost via TCP sockets by setting the `HOST` key in your `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
     [...]
        'HOST': 'localhost',
     [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the psql code above and got this error: psql: FATAL:  role "user" does not exist

Comment: You need to adapt this command to your own context. Replace user by the name of the PostgreSQL user you have created and database_name by your own database name. It seems you're a beginner with both Django and PostgreSQL. I'd recommend you get a bit more familiar with PostgreSQL before trying to connect it to Django: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial.html